# Django template not displaying

Tags: python, django

I have a template for an about page which refuses to show. I'm probably doing something silly but I can't work out why and it's driving me insane!

part of views.py:

```
# About view
def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.views import post as blog_post
from blog.views import profile as blog_profile
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$', 'blog.views.index'),
url(r'^about/$', 'blog.views.about'),
url(r'^profiles/$', 'blog.views.profile_index'),
url(r'^profiles/(?P<profile_url>[\w\-]+)/$', blog_profile, name = 'blog_profile'),
url(r'^(?P<category>[\w\-]+)/$', 'blog.views.categoryIndex'),
url(r'^(?P<category>[\w\-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', blog_post, name = 'blog_post')
)
```

the about template (not including the base.html):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} About {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>About</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Using Django 1.6.5

Tried to navigate to mysite.com/about/

Template hierachy:

```
templates
    base.html
    blog
        about.html
        ....
```

Comment: Could you provide some more details please

Comment: does base.html lie within parent folder of blog? what is your django version?

Comment: @littleswany: it might help if you provide more details about which details you think the OP should provide. For me, it’d be helpful to know where your views and template files are in your project folder hierarchy, and what URL you put into your browser to try to view the rendered template.

Comment: I've added the info you all requested :)

Comment: in base.html, is there {% block content %} tag?

Comment: Yep that's fine. I have other templates using the same content block which are working ok

Comment: Have you added the app to installed apps? 
Can you share the rest of your urls.py?

Comment: Yes I have. I've included the rest of the urls.py

Comment: Whats the response of your call? Empty body or some error? Is DEBUG enabled in settings.py? When adding a `print` statement in your view, does it appear in the server output in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the problem, the following url was being matched with the about page instead:

```
url(r'^(?P<category>[\w\-]+)/$', 'blog.views.categoryIndex'),
```

Removing this solves the issue and displays the about page. This page explains about url ordering http://www.webforefront.com/django/regexpdjangourls.html

Because my about url was listed before the conflicting one, it was skipped.

Comment: No. The ^about/$ rule is set above, so it's matched first.

Answer (score 0):

If your templates dir is at the root level of the project, you might want to add the following to the settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

Comment: he says he has other templates using the same content block which are working ok. means this might not be the problem here